# Why doesn't VIM recognize a color totally available?

Tags: vim

This is mystery drives me crazy: I am trying to specify certain colors that *are* listed inside gVim 7.3 when running [this script](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/View_all_colors_available_to_gvim).

But when put in a .vim syntax file, gVim simply issues an error "Color name not recognized". This happens even with simple colors like `orange`. Instead, it only recognizes a few colors like red, blue, yellow, darkyellow, darkgreen, black, etc.

Why does this happen and how to workaround this?

Comment: what... Vim has color recognition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem by hard coding the offending color (orange) in the `.vim` file:

```
hi def MyOrange_color ctermfg=202 guifg=#ff5f00
```

Answer (score 2):

Because, as a terminal program vim only supports ANSI colors by default.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

I don't know enough about syntax files to fully answer, but these links might be useful
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/View_all_colors_available_to_gvim

It's possible that only the normal colors are available to syntax files from there you can use a different color scheme to reassign the normal colors.
http://vimcasts.org/episodes/creating-colorschemes-for-vim/

Comment: +1. However, I am using gVim, which is *not* a terminal program.

Comment: But gvim is the same program as vim.. and therefore, some of it's defaults are inherited from vim being a terminal program.